# Multi-level expanding child rows in table

Tags: gui-design, tables

I'm trying to design a tabular view in which each item in a row contains about 5 pieces of basic information, the exact number doesn't matter. Some items will consist of multiple child items, which can be viewed by expanding the parent row. Each child has 3 of the 5 pieces of basic information. Some of the children will consist of multiple child items themselves, and so on. The depth of child items in practice probably won't exceed 3/4 but there's no hard limit.

My first basic design is here:
[image]

Here's a slightly improved design, but is still confusing:
[image]

Does anyone have any ideas on how the layout could be improved to make it more obvious what's going on in a manner that can go 4 levels deep or even more?

EDIT: To prevent the page from becoming too complicated in this solution only one sibling will be expanded at a time, so essentially meaning each level is an accordion.

Comment: Any reason why the user has to see the sub tables within the parent tables? What are the pros and cons?

Comment: Are you suggesting a new page for the child items or a different table/layout within the expanded row?

Comment: No, I’m asking for the pros and cons for your current design and your reasoning for choosing it.

Comment: Pros - user can see the child items that make up the parent items without navigating to another page. Cons - could be confusing if layout not well designed.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the answer to this question could be highly dependent on the user's workflow and efficiency.

Common practice recommends opening each child in a separate page to avoid information overload. Just opening a few children in the same page will very quickly make your page super long and overwhelming.

I recommend you test both version (new page vs in-line expansion) with users performing the task they are expected to do.

Comment: To prevent the page from becoming too complicated, if I use the "same page solution", I will only allow one sibling to be expanded at a time, so essentially it will be an accordion at each level.

Comment: What if you have a very extensive sibling and the user opens another parent? Wouldn’t the action of the sibling collapsing coupled with the parent opening mess with the page height and disorient the user?